# How to compute $-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}((n+1)!)^{2}}}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm trying to compute $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{1-x}}}dx$.

I already computed this integral using substitution and IBP and it's value is $4(\ln(2)-1)$.

When I use the serie expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$, I stumble upon $-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}((n+1)!)^{2}}}$ and I have no idea, short of going back to the integral, on how to compute this sum.

If someone has an idea, please share ! Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you already know the result maybe you can do it backwards, start expanding $4(ln(2)-1)$ and see if you can relate both series.